# Is there some standard notation and/or tensorial terminology for this vector product?

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors

Let $V$ be a vector space with basis $(e_1,e_2)$, and $\{\vec{v},\vec{w}\}\in V$, where:
$$\vec{v}=v_1e_1+v_2e_2$$
$$\vec{w}=w_1e_1+w_2e_2$$
And we define the product $*$ to be:
$$\vec{v}*\vec{w}=v_1w_1e_1^2+(v_1w_2+v_2w_1)e_1e_2+v_2w_2e_2^2$$

How is this product called? Is it related to tensors in some way?

Comment: Your notation is confusing, where did you see this product? Are $e_1$ and $e_2$ supposed to be vectors?

Comment: You first need to define what you mean by "product" between the basis vectors. Ie. $e_1$ and $e_2$.  Most definitions will have $e_1e_2 \neq  e_2 e_1$ .  The closest thing to what you want seems to be the outer product:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product

which satisfies $\vec{v}\otimes\vec{w}=v_1w_1(e_1 \otimes e_1)+v_1w_2(e_1 \otimes e_2) +v_2w_1 (e_2 \otimes e_1)+v_2w_2(e_1 \otimes e_2)$ . The outer product between an $m$-vector and an $n$-vector will give you an $m\times n$-matrix (in your case, a $2\times 2$ matrix)

Comment: @DavidRaveh is the standard product of multiplication. Like in $(a_1u+a_2v)(b_1u+b_2v)=a_1b_1u^2+(a_1b_2+a_2b_1)uv+a_2b_2v^2$.

Comment: @SimónFlavioIbañez how do you define u^2 if u is a vector? You need to add context so it is clear what you know and what you don't know about linear algebra

Comment: You can work in $\bigvee^2 V$. See the [symmetric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the product of $v$ and $w$ in the [symmetric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_algebra) $S(V)$; you can call it the "symmetric product" although I don't know if that terminology is standard. This is a coordinate-invariant version of the polynomial algebra.